# Where can I find information about roadmap "pgbouncer", "Etcd", "patroni"?

Tags: etcd, pgbouncer, patroni

Could you please tell me if there is information about the update schedule(when support for different versions ends, when new ones are planned to be released).
Is there a link to this information(graph, table) ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Patroni:

https://github.com/zalando/patroni/blob/master/docs/releases.rst#version-213
https://patroni.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releases.html#

etcd:

https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/milestones
https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/tree/main/CHANGELOG

pgbouncer:

https://www.pgbouncer.org/changelog.html